# Comparing tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, left-join

I have Two tables I want to compare with each other.

```
Table1:                      Table2:

col1  col2 col3                col1  col2 
msp   msp   ...                 msp  msp 
cin   cin   ...                 cnn  cnn 
msp   eri   ...                 cin  cin 
cnn   cnn   ...
was   asc   ...
```

I want the resulting table to look like this:

```
Table3
col1  col2     col3 col4               
msp   msp      msp  msp             
cin   cin      cin  cin             
msp   eri      null null             
cnn   cnn      cnn  cnn 
was   asc      null null
```

I have a query like this but it is not returning it the way I want it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.col1, Table1.col2
FROM TESTDB
LEFT JOIN 
    Table2
    ON Table1.col1 = Table2.col1
    and Table1.col2 = Table2.col2
```

This has been returning:

```
col1  col2     col3 col4               
msp   msp      msp  msp             
cin   cin      cin  cin             
msp   eri      msp  eri             
cnn   cnn      cnn  cnn 
was   asc      was  asc
```

I think there is something wrong with my conditional clause ON. Any help?

Comment: Does this query have a where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Table1.col1, Table1.col2 ,Table2.col1 as col3 ,Table2.col2 as col4 
    FROM Table1
    LEFT JOIN 
    Table2
    ON Table1.col1 = Table2.col1
    and Table1.col2 = Table2.col2
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dab71/1)

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say what's wrong with your query since you showed us an incomplete one (only two columns in SELECT).  If I'm to guess, I would say you didn't alias fields with **the same** name.

This works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1 col11, t1.col2 col12, t2.col1 col21, t2.col2 col22
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN 
    Table2 t2
    ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
    and t2.col2 = t2.col2
```

**SQL Fiddle** is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38ed0/6).